# xcode 5 .xassets migration issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5

In Xcode 4.6 and below I used images to support launch image in landscape for iphone and its working perfectly, but after migrating the aseets to aseetslog (.xassets) folder in new xcode 5 I am not able to c the launch image for IPhone in landscape mode.As my application will run only landscape more.Can any one please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have checked the "Landscape" checkbox in the asset catalog and you have put your proper images.

[image]

Comment: Yes i checked proper images i used and landscape is checked. ?

Comment: In your general project settings is landscape left and right checked?

Comment: Yes checked and when I searched in google, some blogs  observed previously, telling in landscape u cannot set launchimage for iphone, if that is the case how its working 4r me previously